# Users should be able to specify preferred indentation style, and have all viewed code be automatically reformatted accordingly

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-formatting

I believe I'm not the only one who cringe when I see a bad indentation style, and I've heard about others who've had their indentation style in questions be modified by others. Now, I don't belive we will all ever agree on what is the best style, but we can at least avoid this conflict by letting people both read and write in their prefdered style.

The implementation of automatically reformatting the code to personal preference wouldn't be a big problem, right? Ofc the change in formatting could occasionally create confusion, but a simple button to view original formatting would fix that in most cases, I guess.

What do you think? Are there any limitations I haven't thought of?

Comment: wouldn't be a big problem? how many languages do Stack support? how do you "prefer" something in a language, if it breaks features from another one? I honestly feel like you underestimate the difficulty of implementing this... or I'm overestimating it

Comment: Usually it is inappropriate to edit indentation just to change the indentation style. It is appropriate in cases where the indentation isn't actually following any convention at all if editing makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** People are too unpredictable in order to make an algorithm that can figure out, in general, how their code is being indented in the first place, let alone convert that to a person's own indentation style.

However, in real life circumstances when you're looking at code that someone else has worked on, you aren't going to be able to just change their indentation style for your convenience. Sometimes you've just got to focus and not let the cringe factor of bad style distract you from what you've got to do.

---

I'm going to use Python as an example as to why this wouldn't work, because Python is a language that is actually dependent on it's whitespace, unlike many others.

Currently, I see probably at least a question every day where a user has put their code into the question, and the indentation is such that the code literally would not run. Maybe it was a copy/paste error, or when they tried to indent by 4 spaces to make it a code block something went wrong, or maybe there's another reason.

Even though on a small portion of those questions the indentation error is so obvious that it can be corrected by someone editing to make the code valid and thus make the question answerable, most of the time the indentation changes the meaning of the code and the people wanting to answer the question have to wait until the OP edits their code before they can start to understand the question, because the code snippet isn't indented correctly. So these people have indented their code in an unpredictable way that the interpreter won't be able to understand.

So even if I like having my Python code indentation set to 2 spaces all the time, and lots of people like it set to 4, a "Figure out what indentation this code is using, and change it to 2 spaces" algorithm would still fail on many questions every day in Python because people don't indent their code in a predictable way and the code will be wrongly matched by the algorithm, even though the language naturally forces people to follow very strict indentation rules.

Now take one of the many, many languages in which indentation makes no difference to the interpreter's/compiler's ability to understand the code. So nothing is forcing coders to follow any predictable indentation pattern. If in a language like Python where programmers need to follow strict indentation rules still has enough variance to make an algorithm understanding how their code is indented very difficult in the first place, then with other languages it would only be that much more difficult to program an algorithm that accounts for all the possible variations to figure out how a block of code is being indented.

And we're not even getting into how to tell the algorithm what language it's supposed to be looking at in the first place, that's a whole can of worms in itself and could affect the indentation rules.

I work in a software development job in which about half the time I'm working on C code, and the other half, on bash/ksh scripts. Usually I'm editing existing code, and I've had to see a lot of different indentation styles that have been used by my co-workers going back in some cases even 20 and 30 years. I've learned that the only thing that can really be done is to just get used to seeing code in different indentation, formatting and documentation styles, because in real life situations, you'll have to deal with things as they are. Sometimes you've just got to focus and not let the cringe factor of bad style distract you from what you've got to do.